# Merge string cell arrays and remove duplicates

Tags: string, matlab, duplicates, cell-array

I've the following string cell arrays:

```
a = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
b = { 'E', 'A', 'F', 'D'};
```

How can I merge them and remove duplicate strings, so I can obtain the following string cell array?

```
c = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [union](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html):

```
union(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Combine Cell Arrays](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html?requestedDomain=true) and [`unique`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html?searchHighlight=unique&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)

```
unique([a,b])
```